# Not sure if its best to use a wrapper class or static for a variable that needs to be seen by multiple threads

Tags: java

I am still learning about java and need a recommendation on best practices.

Here is the scenerio:

1. An encrypted file comes in
2. A java app picks up the file when it comes.
3. The java app from the class that listens for the file, in its main method creates 5 blockingqueues (for the consumers), starts up a producer and 5 consumer threads.
4. The producer thread reads the file and creates 1 big object consisting of 5 other smaller objects within it.
5. The producer thread then puts each big object into the blockingqueues.
6. Each consumer thread looks into its own blockingqueue, retrieves the big object, then it retrieves 1 of the 5 smaller objects and writes a file with the information related to that 1 small object.

my problem:
If anything goes wrong in the producer thread while its reading the file, I want the listening class (the one that starts everything up) to know about it so that it can change the extension of the encrypted file to .err

I also want the other 5 consumer threads to know if something wrong occurs in the producer thread so that they can also change the extension of the file that each creates to .err

Not sure if a wrapper class would be recommended more in this scenerio that I pass into the blockingqueue or to use a static variable in the listening or producer class that all the threads can look at to know if an error occurred. Thank you for your help

or if there is a better solution please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if instead of having each child thread write out their results to a file, the results were aggregated back to a result handler? This way if there was an error, the result handler can handle it appropriately (by adding the .err extension).

Most of the performance advantages of concurrency have to do with better CPU usage, but since you're writing to a single piece of hardware (disk, probably) there really isn't an advantage to doing that concurrently anyway.

The main disadvantage to this approach would be that your memory overhead would be a little bigger, since you would have to keep the outputs  from each consumer in memory until all five had finished writing, instead of being able to have them each finish and persist separately. Honestly, you'll have to do that anyway, since an error in one consumer could happen after some other consumer had already finished and persisted.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this